# My wife doesn't want to live with me anymore

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I married Aela and built a house where we lived for a long time. I have the tendency of taking my wife as a follower on quests. However, one time after I dismissed her she returned to Jorrvaskr and I don't have the ability to tell her to go to my house. I tried telling her to go to Breezehome and Hjerimm, to which she agreed but remained at Jorrvaskr. That being said, traveling to Whiterun and taking her as a follower from there is fine and all but after she left I had to give my two daughters daggers so that they can kill wolves that attack my house and that's just awful parenting.

She is my first wife, so it's not the same bug I've seen other people have where their first wife dies and they remarry but their new wife refuses to go to their house. I married and lived with her at Lakeview a long time ago so I don't have a save from before this bug happened. Also, it's not a modded version of the game. Is there a way I can fix this because it's really ruining the RP in RPG for me?

Comment: Couple's counselling?

Comment: @deworde Finding a good therapist in Skyrim is hard, though. And the life of a mere blacksmith dragonborn adventurer only gets me so much gold.

Comment: Hm, is Aela actually marriable without mods? Maybe she simply is not meant to move out of Jorrvaskr (or her standard routines will restart after reset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. Well, I guess "fix" is the word.
What I did was tell her to go to the house and then followed her on foot the whole way there. A slow method, indeed, but she is staying at the house for now.

Comment: Glad to hear you and your wife are working through your problems, even if it took a long time to get there ;)

Comment: @B17 She needs to learn to walk faster, yeah...

Answer (score 0):

Try having her as a follower. Give her the same amulet that you married with. Next part ways and leave. Return to her and use the same option you used to marry her by rehiring her.

Answer (score 0):

Try making her follow you, as [@lucklady41](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/151229/luckylady41) said. Then tell her to move to where you want to live, and then go to that place.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your wife thinks that she isn't going to a actual house since a DLC is just a add on. Original houses in skyrim probably work, but I bet building your own is quite buggy; even after a few patches. Maybe to help this situation you can use a mod called "Spouses can live everywhere." -http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/11370/. You will need the nexus mod manager to install it. After you have installed it, you should have a new spell called "mark new home" and it will help your wife see your house as her home.

Comment: No, the house worked before and original houses worked before but neither of them work now. She does recognize them as houses, agrees to go there but then stays at Jorrvaskr.

Comment: maybe she is cheating on you~ kill everyone inside Jorrvaskr (except your wife if you want) and see where it goes.

Comment: I had many problems with Jorrvaskr myself. Maybe the place itself is just glitchy